# I can’t figure out how to set my random number between 1 and 100

Tags: android

I just want to make a basic counter and for some reason I can't figure out how to draw a random number between 1 and 100. Can someone please explain what I have to do to draw a random number between 1 and 100?

This is what I came up with until now:

```
int value;
private int count = 1;

Random rand;


}
```

Comment: I suggest you only post the relevant lines of code, not your entire file.  In your case, it's probably 1 line, possibly 2.

Comment: yeah I just realized that like right after you said it :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();

  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
  log("Generated : " + randomInt);
```

Comment: This code returns a number between 0 and 99, as it uses the the half-open range [0, 100). See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: Do you know how to make 
First is 1 and second 2 and so will continue till reaches 100

Answer (score 4):

Looks like for integers you need to create a random generator object first:

```
//at the start of your program
Random generator = new Random();

//each time you need a random number
int myrandomnumber = generator.nextInt()%100+1;
```

Comment: so something like rand = (Math.random()/100 + 1?

Comment: yeah I realized the % would mak more sense seeing as / would only = like 20k lol

Comment: quick question I went to get it using your code and for some reason it doesnt want to like it....

Answer (score 4):

Try using this..

```
Random rander = new Random();
int Max = 100;
int Min = 1;
rander.nextInt(Max - Min  + 1) + Min ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mRandom = minLimit + (int) (Math.random() * ((maxlimit - minLimit) + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
int Min = 1;
int Max = 100;
int rndNum = Math.random() * ( Max - Min );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard really.

Try using this:

`int randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);`

For a number between 0-100. 
Or, if you want a value between X and Y, use the following:

`int randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * X) + Y;`

Where Y is the lowest number you want, and X is the highest number you want to add to it (for instance Y = 75 and X = 25 so you get a number between 75 and 100 (75+25) )

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has ben answered I would like to say that you can use floats doubles as well
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0):

below code, boudary value between 1 to 100

```
        int maxValue = 100;
        int randomValueInt = new Random().nextInt(maxValue) + 1;
```

below code, boudary value between 0 to 99

```
        int maxValue = 100;
        int randomValueInt = new Random().nextInt(maxValue);
```

below code, boudary value between 0 to 100

```
        int maxValue = 100;
        int randomValueInt = new Random().nextInt(maxValue + 1);
```